# console log is already filtered before filter

Tags: javascript, filter

so i have no problem at all i am just curious why my code is acting weird, first console log is already filtered before filter function, is this some kind of bug or something? can anyone explain it to me or redirect me to docs?

```
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users') || '[]');

    console.log(users)

    
    for(let user of users)
    {
      if(user.email === currentUser.email)
      {
        user.groups = user.groups.filter( (group:string) => group !== groupName )
        
      }
    }

    console.log(users);
```

Comment: If you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(users))` you will see that it's not filtered. The console is just being lazy and not evaluating it at the time of the call, but at the time you look at it.

Comment: yes thanks both of you